# How to remove the last N bytes from a file

Tags: file, go, io

I want to delete thelast N bytes from file in Go,

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is already implemented is the [`os.Truncate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Truncate) function. But this function takes the new size. So to use this, you have to first get the size of the file. For that, you may use [`os.Stat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat).

Wrapping it into a function:

```
func truncateFile(name string, bytesToRemove int64) error {
    fi, err := os.Stat(name)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return os.Truncate(name, fi.Size()-bytesToRemove)
}
```

Using it to remove the last 5000 bytes:

```
if err := truncateFile("C:\\Test.zip", 5000); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
```

Another alternative  is to use the [`File.Truncate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Truncate) method for that. If we have an `os.File`, we may also use [`File.Stat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Stat) to get its size.

This is how it would look like:

```
func truncateFile(name string, bytesToRemove int64) error {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(name, os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return f.Truncate(fi.Size() - bytesToRemove)
}
```

Using it is the same. This may be preferable if we're working on a file (we have it opened) and we have to truncate it. But in that case you'd want to pass `os.File` instead of its name to `truncateFile()`.

Note: if you try to remove more bytes than the file currently has, `truncateFile()` will return an error.

Comment: Thank you, sir, That's ok now

Comment: @Pwn3rGamer Actually this is already implemented in `os.Truncate()`. See edited answer.